# How to prepare dev extreme charts on ng repeat for multiple data

Tags: html, angularjs, devexpress

In `ng repeat` multiple data not binding to `dx chart`

am saving multiple data set in `$scope.TestDataset`,
but pie chart not adding automatically

i want to multiple pie charts for multiple datasource

## HTML

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="demo-container" ng-repeat="testP in TestDataset[0]">
                <div id="pie" dx-pie-chart="testP"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## JS

```
var dataSource = [
       [ {
        country: "Russia",
        area: 50,
        other: 20
    }, {
        country: "Canada",
        area: 50,
        other: 26
    }],
      [{
          country: "India",
          area: 50,
          other: 20
      }, {
          country: "China",
          area: 50,
          other: 26
      }]

    ];
    var ttCol = [{ Val1: "country", Val2: "area" }, { Val1: "country", Val2: "other" }]

    $scope.TestDataset1 = [];
    for (i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {

            $scope.chartOptionsTest = [{
                size: {
                    width: 500
                },
                palette: "bright",
                dataSource: dataSource[i],
                series: [
                    {
                        argumentField: ttCol[i].Val1,
                        valueField: ttCol[i].Val2,
                        label: {
                            visible: true,
                            connector: {
                                visible: true,
                                width: 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                title: "Area of Countries",
                "export": {
                    enabled: true
                },
                onPointClick: function (e) {
                    var point = e.target;

                    toggleVisibility(point);
                },
                onLegendClick: function (e) {
                    var arg = e.target;

                    toggleVisibility(this.getAllSeries()[0].getPointsByArg(arg)[0]);
                }
            }];
            $scope.TestDataset1.push($scope.chartOptionsTest)
        }
    $scope.TestDataset = $scope.TestDataset1;

 //$scope.TestDataset = $scope.TestDataset1[0];
//if i bind data like this one pie chart is loading
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.chartOptionsTest` is an array in your code. It should be an object. Remove square brackets.

```
$scope.chartOptionsTest = {
    size: {
        width: 500
    },
    palette: "bright",
    dataSource: dataSource[i],
    series: [
        {
            argumentField: ttCol[i].Val1,
            valueField: ttCol[i].Val2,
            label: {
                visible: true,
                connector: {
                    visible: true,
                    width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    title: "Area of Countries",
    "export": {
        enabled: true
    }
};
```

Then, your markup will be:

```
<div class="demo-container" ng-repeat="testP in TestDataset">
    <div id="pie" dx-pie-chart="testP"></div>
</div>
```

See the [CodePen sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjRypm?editors=0010).